# Frequency properties of posterior predictive checked bayesian models

Tags: bayesian, frequentist

Does a bayesian model passing a posterior predictive check imply any frequency properties outside the tested data?

Comment: In short, the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks Xi'an . What about the parameter uncertainty or credible intervals if the model is misspecified (complex system etc)?

Do they "mean" anything?

Comment: All models are misspecified, but the credible intervals are still useful guides as long as the misspecification isn't too bad (for which a leap of faith is required.)